# CakePHP routes named parameters in base path (/)

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.2

I get user referrer with `r` parameter. (`r:code`).

It works well on all `:controller/:action/*` pages, but when try to pass it to base path (/), my webserver returns error 403.

Here is my `routes.php` file:

```
    Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
    Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
    Router::connectNamed(array('r' => '[\d]{4}'));
```

These URLs works well:

```
http://example.com/pages/home/r:1234
http://example.com/apples/eat/r:1234
```

but it doesn't work:

```
http://example.com/r:1234
```

What's wrong?

**Question:** Is it the way to capture referrer code from URL? or it's better to use passed arguments? (`http://example.com/1234/controller/action/.......`)

Answer (score 2):

Apache 2.2 actually the APR `test_safe_name()` function intentionally disallows this kind of 
":" character within a URI on Windows servers. because This is basically for avoiding URLs like http://www.mysite.com/C:/SomeFile.exe but is actually annoying. 
Also, the Windows `FindFirstFile()` function will return `ERROR_INVALID_NAME`
instead of `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` for any name attempting data stream access using
the ":" character.
**The choice of the ":" character as the namespace separator in MediaWiki was an
unfortunate one for use on Windows servers .**

Comment: @AD7six: Yes, my localhost is a Windows PC.

Comment: Hi Ali Reza (salam!). Is it possible to change `:` to another character? For example, change it to `-`.

Comment: @kikio [you can](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Routing/Router.php#L422) but is it really worth it. p.s. [google your error messages](https://www.google.com/search?q=cakephp+(20024)+The+given+path+misformatted+or+contained+invalid+characters) =)

Answer (score 1):

### Use a get argument

If you use a get argument - your code will be a lot more robust:

```
/?r=urlencodedurl
```

This is independent of routes and therefore won't break or otherwise be a problem irrespective of the url used. You access get args via the request object:

```
$r = $this->request->query['r']
```